# 3D Secure Payments With PayU Payment Gateway Using Expresso Store/Omnipay

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway, omnipay

I am integrating the PayU payment gateway into EE2 by using store and Omnipay. The on-page payment gateway allows the user to pay via credit card, but with 3DSecure enabled to provide an extra layer of security. Hoe would I go about displaying the OTP pin page to the user so he can enter the pin received via SMS, submit this and get on with the transaction?

I got the testing payment to go through successfully, but just need to cater for this 3dsecure feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hein

Please look at this [Omnipay with 3D secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712519/omnipay-with-3d-secure) as a point of reference; as each gateway will require that the Secure 3D process be implemented differently and as such the payment process steps for the module will have to be applied in this manner.

In the case of PayU MEA, [3D Secure (Enterprise API)](http://help.payu.co.za/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2654358) is a good reference.